# SSRS 2012 total of a percentage measure

Tags: ssrs-2012, percentage, ssas-2012

I have a percentage measure calculated in SSAS tabular and its correct.
But when i use it in a report i face the following problem (in all percentage measures).

[image]

the values under **male** and **female** (which are subgroup of **saudi** and **non-saudi**) are correct but if you look at the total under "**Both sexes**" it is incorrect,because it shows summation of male and female percentage, where the right thing is it shows the percentage of the saudi or non-saudi.

If i calculate the measure in SSRS in the expression fields i get it right as follows

[image]

But i want to use the measure to show the right values.

So.. can anyone help me with this i have serious issues in later reports and i just cant simply recalculate the SSAS measures in SSRS using expressions.

Note: dont mind the decimal places differences between the two pics.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your MDX query in SSRS to return the subtotal rows then change your Textbox formulas in the body of the Report to say `=Aggregate` instead of `=Sum`. This process is described more [here](http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/03/08/retrieving-aggregate-data/) by Stacia. You can use manual MDX queries. Don't miss the comment at the bottom:

> Romuald Coutaud March 17, 2011 at 7:52 pm Hi Stacia,
>
> In fact, it works in query mode too in 2008R2. But, I have to admit
>   that the way that RS and AS work together when you want to use
>   aggregate function is very difficult to perfectly understand and I
>   have struggle very long time to make one sample report running in this
>   way. In query mode you need to write MDX by referencing each level of
>   the hierarchies from the top one to the deepest one want to display in
>   your report, even you don’t need to use all these ones. As an example
>   you have to put Year, Quarter and Month to be sure to display Month
>   and be able to use aggregate function.

Basically in your report `=Aggregate` will try to retrieve a row where Nationality is not null and Gender is null. If you get stuck please write back with the list of each field used in each group in SSRS and a screenshot of the MDX query designer.

Comment: I saw some comments and then they disappeared. Did you get this working?

Comment: yeah i apologize it did work for the percentage measure in the example above but in another reports where i use MEAN and Median, when it comes to MEAN it works but it give incorrect value in grand total and in median it just gives me blanks and zeros for everything i am not very good with mdx, so i wasnt able to find how to edit the query i can give you a screen shots of the MEAN and MEDIAN example in another question.

Comment: heres the problem i am facing right now
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374786/ssrs-2012-mean-median